# How to see user's files on google drive via angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, google-api, google-drive-api

I've read almost all api reference in [google](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference). There was a method to get a file or upload a file. In get file you need to pass `file id`:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'fileId': fileId
  });
```

But what I want to achieve is to get users permission through my app (client app), and I then should see users' files. User himself should choose one of the the files.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the purpose is to allow the user to choose one of his own files, then you might want to consider using the JS Picker https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

If you really want to retrieve the list of files into your app, then the simplest way is to use $http.get with a url of  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files

In your question you posted code to do a GET, rather than a LIST. GET (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) will fetch all of the meta data for a single file, given its ID. LIST (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) will fetch meta data for all files (generally qualified with a q parameter to filter out trashed files).

Comment: What I actually needed was `JS picker`. Thank you very much. ;-)